# DNSSEC is not configured for X website

Tags: dns, dnssec, dns-rebinding

I'm pretty new to this world of security and I'm doing some challenges trying to solve puzles of security, the thing is I have a website that is not loading it throws a timeout if I do ping, but playing with nslookup dig I've found an IP that responds to the ping, and in the path of finding this IP I found that the website I'm trying to get admin privileges have :

> [ - ] DNSSEC is not configured for this website

And I'm wondering if this could be the vulnerability of the puzzle because I need to have admin privileges of the machine (there's only a website) I've been checking the `dns-rebind` I could execute this command but don't know if it's usefull

```
dns-rebind -i ech0 -d website
 starting dns server on port X
 starting web server on port 80
 ...
 services started and running!
```

I don't know if I'm in the correct way, perhaps this DNSSEC is not the way to get acces to the maching and I'm losing too much time here.

Having this "open" I can do DNS spoofing right? Does it help to me to enter to server and change privilegies?

Answer (score 0):

DNSSEC secures DNS replies, if the domain is enabled for DNSSEC, by basically adding cryptographic signatures to any DNS reply, so that the consumer (resolver) can double check the information received is legit and really coming from owner of the zone.

As such, this does not help in favor or against access to any resource. It just makes sure that, typically the IP addresses you got are legit (but that happens only under two conditions 1) the domain is DNSSEC enabled and 2) the resolver you use is validating answers).

If DNSSEC is enabled on a domain, an attacker will have more difficulty (nothing is 100% absolute) to divert victims to other resources (hijacking DNS replies, or BGP routing, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for answering but I guess that the website have DNSSEC disable that's why I'd like to know if having this disable I can do something to connect to this virtual machine

Comment: "that the website have DNSSEC disable". No. DNSSEC is a DNS feature and applies to the whole zone if enabled.

Comment: What I mean that doing a dnsrecon I saw that DNSSEC is not enabled and I want to know if with this I can do something or not.